# Streaming audio for Ruby on rails application running on LAN with front end server & Audio files on different machines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, centos

I have a ruby on rails application:
1. It use jplayer as audio player 
2. Right now the audio files and the application server are on one machine.
3. I want to separate audio files and server running application on different machines .So that I can stream audio from their on LAN. 
4. I have already separated the database from the server running application 
5. I am using cent 0S 5.8 in all 3 machines
   one for running ROR application , 2nd for database, 3rd for audio streaming.
can any one give me an Idea 
thanks

Comment: do you want everything from the browser to go through the RoR app?  Or will your client browser be expected to connect to the three different servers.

Comment: yes, audio hosted on one server should be used by the other server hosting the ROR app which is playing audio files. More over database is already on different machine which is working fine. for doing it I have given grant permission to DB and small changes in database.yaml in ROR app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring streaming for now,  here is a simple example of a rails app calling another rails app :

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse("http://yourother.com/getaudio/#{@audio.id}")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
resp = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req)}
play_your_audio(resp.body)
```

Note the use of GET,  so we don't have to worry about authenticating.

Here is a good article about streaming IO and Rails:

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/5/24/building-streaming-rest-apis-with-ruby